# Dockerfile Unknown flag: chown

Tags: docker

My Dockerfile is failing on the below step:

```
ADD --chown=user:user test.py /etc/test
```

Any suggestions on how can I fix it? I am using AWS EC2 instance RHEL 7.6
Updating with docker version output below:

```
Client:
 Version:         1.13.1
 API version:     1.26
 Package version: docker-1.13.1-88.git07f3374.el7.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.10.2
 Git commit:      07f3374/1.13.1
 Built:           Thu Dec  6 07:01:49 2018
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:         1.13.1
 API version:     1.26 (minimum version 1.12)
 Package version: docker-1.13.1-88.git07f3374.el7.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.10.2
 Git commit:      07f3374/1.13.1
 Built:           Thu Dec  6 07:01:49 2018
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64
 Experimental:    false
```

Please advice on how to update to more latest verison of docker if that's the issue

Comment: Looks OK to me, on which docker version does this happen?

Answer (score 8):

Docker 17.09+ is required for this syntax. I think you may need upgrade your Docker.

Or just try change to these lines:

```
ADD test.py /etc/test
RUN sudo chown -R user:user /etc/test/test.py
```

Comment: I am getting error `sudo: not found`.Can you share the steps to upgrade Docker in RHEL

Comment: Just remove old version and install the newest version: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ee/rhel/ . Sorry but i'm not using RHEL

Comment: Apparently RHEL supports only Docker EE. One needs to have subscription for it I believe.

Comment: Even upgrading to 17.09 won't help, Docker is having some issue.I am using v18.09 and facing issue.